# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test\src'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I had created a test named folder using create-react-app test and after successful creation of folder when doing npm start getting this error

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test\src'
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I had tried removing yarn.lock file then yarn install but error is not fixed.

Comment: Try removing `package-lock.json`, run `npm install` and then `npm start` again.

Comment: already tried this but this also doesn't fix my problem , my folder doesn't have the  package-lock.json  file instead have yarn.lock so removed this file and run npm install but problem is not solved

Comment: Have you tried creating new react app with different name?

Comment: yes tried that also at different location but getting same error

Comment: Make sure that `node_modules/react` exists. If not, update yarn or try using npm. If none of that helps, you will have to file new issue here - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues

Comment: I checked the node_module/react exist but inside react folder are some folders & file that are missing when i compared it with my older app i created.

Comment: File new issue, that doesn't belong to StackOverflow anymore, sorry.

Comment: So finally after wasting my whole day, i had done yarn clear cache and npm clear cache and again created create-react-app and problem is solved!! But why clearing cache worked ??

Comment: I guess you ran npm start inside of src folder, not in the test folder / root project.

Comment: Hi Shubham, please see my answer and upvote and mark it as an answer if it worked properly.

Answer (score 5):

1. Remove `package-lock.json` file.
2. Run `npm install` command.
3. Try to execute `npm start` again.

**PS:** You can also use `pnpm` instead of `npm` by installing its package via `npm i -g pnpm` command. pnpm package has some benefits compare to npm command that you can read the complete difference in [this site](https://pnpm.js.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line of code

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
```

replace by

```
import DatePicker from "../react-datepicker";
```

or else

have to install packages

```
npm install react-datepicker --save
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using faker then remove from your index.js file

```
import Faker from 'faker';
```

Remove above line

Answer (score 0):

I had encounter similar error, I wrote:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom ";
```

instead of :

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

Remove the extra space or check for any syntax error.